# Powershell - Append CSV column wise

Tags: powershell

I have an array and i want to export it to CSV and I use below code.

```
[string[]] $Params = "Foo", "Bar"
$Params | out-file "D:\Output.csv" -Encoding ascii -Force -Append

#Output
Foo
Bar
Foo1
Bar1
Foo2
Bar2
```

It appends the CSV in row wise and i want it to in column wise like below,

```
Foo, Bar
Foo1, Bar1
Foo2, Bar2
```

Somebody please help to get a solution...

Comment: Hi, see my answer. If that's not what you want, please provide more context so we can try to help you (such as maybe a bigger array sample / additional details) .

Comment: Thanks Sage.. Am a newbie, For me its little difficult to understand Powershell objects. i have tried your code to convert to csv, but it returns length of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want in the result is to combine the 1st value in the array with the 2nd and so on, a simple for loop would do:

```
[string[]] $Params = "Foo", "Bar","Foo1", "Bar1","Foo2", "Bar2"
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Params.Count -1; $i+=2 ) {
    # if any of the strings in the $Params array contains spaces 
    # or comma's I would strongly suggest quoting the output.
    '"{0}","{1}"' -f $Params[$i], $Params[$i+1]
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV (no headers)
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\output.csv'
```

Output of the above:

> ```
> "Foo","Bar"
> "Foo1","Bar1"
> "Foo2","Bar2"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ConvertTo-CSV` then output to file or `ExportTo-Csv`.

For that to work, you will use it on a collection of object.

Here's a randomly generated array of `PSObject` that contains a  `Foo` and `Bar` property.
Once I have the object (you would use yours instead), you just have to do like I did in the last line.

**Example**

```
$Array = for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Foo = "Meh-$(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 20)"
        Bar = get-random
    }    
}

# The actual thing that matter
$Array | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | out-file "D:\Output.csv" -Encoding ascii -Force
```

**Random CSV output result**

[image: RandomCSVOutputResult]

Answer (score 0):

You could write the csv file manually yourself(I find this gives you more control in getting the output you want):

```
[string[]] $Params = "Foo", "Bar"
$fileStream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("D:\Output.csv",1)
foreach($p in $Params){
    $fileStream.Write($p+",")
}
$fileStream.Write("`n")
$fileStream.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you... Its overwriting the exist values, i want to append.

Comment: @Enock, I edited my answer that it should now append to the file. Here is a link to documentation for the .net StreamWriter class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.. but its writing all the values by column wise. I want to write first two elements column wise, for next iteration it should move to next row and write the values column wise..

Comment: @Enock, so you just have to write a new line character where you need it. I edited my code above as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Take this:

```
[string[]] $params = "Foo", "Bar"

$params -join ', ' | out-file "D:\Output.csv" -Encoding ascii -Force -Append
```

Comment: Its working fine, the only drawback is its writing everything in a cell. We are going to use this CSV file as a data seeding in Performance testing. So let me check whether its working or not.. Thank you for your efforts..

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = "Foo", "Bar"
$params -join ', ' | Out-File C:\temp\test.csv
```

And then use Text to columns filtering on the , in Excel.